# How do I get the results of a view and store them in a php var?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a custom view that I set up in drupal. What I would like to do is make a function call of some kind, and then assign the results to a php variable. I would like the contents of the view (as opposed to the results of a view export) in this new variable. Is this feasible? If it is a function call, I would appreciate a small example too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done too much hacking around in views, but it looks like maybe `views_embed_view()` might be what you are looking for. I found a good overview of the views API here: http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/view-views-api

Answer (score 1):

You can get the view object with function views_get_view($view_name).

If what you mean by contents of the view is the view object itself you'll need simply:

```
$view = views_get_view('name_of_the_view');
```

However, if you mean the data returned by your view you'll need a little bit more.

```
$results = views_get_view_result('name_of_the_view', 'display_id');
```

At last, if you wish to have more control you can try another approach, creating the view object and working on it afterwards.

```
//variables for your view, display and resulting array    

$my_view_name = 'yourview';
$my_display_name = 'yourdisplay';
$my_arguments = array();

//Creating the view object and configuring it
$view = views_get_view($my_view_name);
if ($my_arguments){
    $view->set_arguments($my_arguments);
}
$view->get_total_rows = True;
$view->set_items_per_page(0);
$view->build($my_display_name);
$view->execute($my_display_name);

//now you have your data array
$view_results_array = $view->result;
```